# MainActivity with ActionBar and ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Basically I've got an `ActionBarActivity` that loads `activity_main.xml` which contains my `ListFragment`
My `ActionBar` has an `Add` button on it, to add items to the list.
Problem I've run into now, is how do I handle the Add and pass the information to the `ListFragment` to populate the `ListView`?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //activity_main only contains <fragment ... /> to add my ListFragment
    }
    ....
    // This is called from onOptionsItemSelected
    private void showAddDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        InputDialog inputDialog = new AddInputDialog();
        inputDialog.setOnUpdateListener(new InputDialog.onUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(Item item){
                //I'm lost at what to do here...
            }
        });
        inputDialog.show(fm, "fragment_dialog_input");
    }
```

**EDIT**
Got it working using `findFragmentById()`, and posted answer below. 
I kept trying to get it to work using `findFragmentByTag()` and even though I had a `TAG` set in my fragment, and when debugging it(the TAG) showed correctly, for some reason would always return `null`.

Comment: Create a public method in the Fragment to add an item to the data list. We can't really be more specific without more code.

Comment: I did that, I wasn't sure how to go about accessing that. Guess I was asking the wrong question. Got it working now though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fragment is defined in `activity_main.xml` use [findFragmentById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)) using the  specified `android:id` then you can call your public function within the `ListFragment` to update the list and notify adapter.

```
private void showAddDialog() {
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    InputDialog inputDialog = new AddInputDialog();
    inputDialog.setOnUpdateListener(new InputDialog.onUpdateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Item item){
            ListFragment lf =  (ListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
            lf.addItem(item);
        }
    });
    inputDialog.show(fm, "fragment_dialog_input");
}
```